# Does Spring have any solution for Web Scraping?

Tags: spring, web-scraping, web-crawler

I need to build a web application which is going to scrape and crawl some websites and extract data and crawlers will have scheduler. I know there are plenty of tools for parsing and extracting data like Jsoup, but I just want to know whether I can implement this with Spring Tools or not?

Comment: The short answer is yes...you can use jsoup together with spring :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no one single template project available from Spring which fits your case. But you can definitely achieve what you want through Spring. Spring provides many [template projects](http://spring.io/projects) to develop different kind of applications. There is [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) project to quickly get started with a web application. There is [Spring Scheduler](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) project for scheduling tasks. I would suggest combine these two and develop your application.

For crawling and Scraping, I believe there are no templates available from Spring. But you can do it using [jSpider](http://j-spider.sourceforge.net/) and [jSoup](https://jsoup.org/).